# Bodymovin - Lottie in Rails project : json in not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, svg, bodymovin

As in the tutorial here : https://aescripts.com/bodymovin/ I try to render my svg in my rails project. 
I think I can find the player but not the json : 
My typescript file looks like this :

```
const bodymovin = require("../player/securite.js");

const animation = bodymovin.loadAnimation({
      container: document.getElementById('json-test'),
      renderer: 'svg',
      loop: true, 
      autoplay: true, 
      path: "app/json/securite.json"
})
```

With that, I have the error `404 (Not Found)`. I also tried to put my json file in my Javascript folder: same result, in my assets: same result. 
Do you know where I should put my json file in my project rails ? Also using gulp, is there any compatibility issue ?

Comment: Have you tried to put the file to the root and write its name in the path as it is on a video you linked to?

Comment: yep, still not found